# Mounting a disk from SAN (RHEL 5.9)

Tags: redhat, storage-area-network, diskmanagement, multipath

Storage admin told me he put a 3TB drive on my server from the SAN and I was asked to mount it. The only information I know is that it's on LUN 1 and that the disk is 3TB.

Multipath is setup and I have QLogic drives installed. I'm not sure what to do now though... there are so many disks how can I find the right one to mount? I told the storage guy I'm seeing everything on the SAN, but I just got "I don't know Linux" from him. I'm not sure what questions to ask to figure out what disk to mount.

This is the output of `fsdisk -l`:

```
Disk /dev/cciss/c0d0: 299.9 GB, 299959511040 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 36468 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

           Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/cciss/c0d0p1   *           1          13      104391   83  Linux
/dev/cciss/c0d0p2              14       36468   292824787+  8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/dm-0: 32.2 GB, 32212254720 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 3916 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes


Disk /dev/dm-1: 267.6 GB, 267630149632 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 32537 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 107.3 GB, 107374182400 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 13054 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System

Disk /dev/sdb: 3298.5 GB, 3298534883328 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 401024 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1               1      267350  2147483647+  ee  EFI GPT

Disk /dev/sdc: 214.7 GB, 214748364800 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 26108 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System

Disk /dev/sdd: 107.3 GB, 107374182400 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 13054 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System

Disk /dev/sde: 3298.5 GB, 3298534883328 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 401024 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sde1               1      267350  2147483647+  ee  EFI GPT

Disk /dev/sdf: 214.7 GB, 214748364800 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 26108 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System

Disk /dev/sdg: 107.3 GB, 107374182400 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 13054 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System

Disk /dev/sdh: 3298.5 GB, 3298534883328 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 401024 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdh1               1      267350  2147483647+  ee  EFI GPT

Disk /dev/sdi: 214.7 GB, 214748364800 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 26108 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System

Disk /dev/sdj: 107.3 GB, 107374182400 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 13054 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System

Disk /dev/sdk: 3298.5 GB, 3298534883328 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 401024 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdk1               1      267350  2147483647+  ee  EFI GPT

Disk /dev/sdl: 214.7 GB, 214748364800 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 26108 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System

Disk /dev/sdm: 107.3 GB, 107374182400 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 13054 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System

Disk /dev/sdn: 3298.5 GB, 3298534883328 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 401024 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdn1               1      267350  2147483647+  ee  EFI GPT

Disk /dev/sdo: 214.7 GB, 214748364800 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 26108 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System

Disk /dev/sdp: 107.3 GB, 107374182400 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 13054 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System

Disk /dev/sdq: 3298.5 GB, 3298534883328 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 401024 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdq1               1      267350  2147483647+  ee  EFI GPT

Disk /dev/sdr: 214.7 GB, 214748364800 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 26108 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System

Disk /dev/sds: 107.3 GB, 107374182400 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 13054 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System

Disk /dev/sdt: 3298.5 GB, 3298534883328 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 401024 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdt1               1      267350  2147483647+  ee  EFI GPT

Disk /dev/sdu: 214.7 GB, 214748364800 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 26108 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System

Disk /dev/sdv: 107.3 GB, 107374182400 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 13054 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System

Disk /dev/sdw: 3298.5 GB, 3298534883328 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 401024 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdw1               1      267350  2147483647+  ee  EFI GPT

Disk /dev/sdx: 214.7 GB, 214748364800 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 26108 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System

Disk /dev/sdy: 107.3 GB, 107374182400 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 13054 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System

Disk /dev/sdz: 3298.5 GB, 3298534883328 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 401024 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdz1               1      267350  2147483647+  ee  EFI GPT

Disk /dev/sdaa: 214.7 GB, 214748364800 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 26108 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

    Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System

Disk /dev/sdab: 107.3 GB, 107374182400 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 13054 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

    Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System

Disk /dev/sdac: 3298.5 GB, 3298534883328 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 401024 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

    Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdac1               1      267350  2147483647+  ee  EFI GPT

Disk /dev/sdad: 214.7 GB, 214748364800 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 26108 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

    Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System

Disk /dev/sdae: 107.3 GB, 107374182400 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 13054 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

    Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System

Disk /dev/sdaf: 3298.5 GB, 3298534883328 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 401024 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

    Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdaf1               1      267350  2147483647+  ee  EFI GPT

Disk /dev/sdag: 214.7 GB, 214748364800 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 26108 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

    Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System

Disk /dev/sdah: 107.3 GB, 107374182400 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 13054 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

    Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System

Disk /dev/sdai: 3298.5 GB, 3298534883328 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 401024 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

    Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdai1               1      267350  2147483647+  ee  EFI GPT

Disk /dev/sdaj: 214.7 GB, 214748364800 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 26108 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

    Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System

Disk /dev/sdak: 107.3 GB, 107374182400 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 13054 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

    Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System

Disk /dev/sdal: 3298.5 GB, 3298534883328 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 401024 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

    Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdal1               1      267350  2147483647+  ee  EFI GPT

Disk /dev/sdam: 214.7 GB, 214748364800 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 26108 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

    Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System

Disk /dev/sdan: 107.3 GB, 107374182400 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 13054 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

    Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System

Disk /dev/sdao: 3298.5 GB, 3298534883328 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 401024 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

    Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdao1               1      267350  2147483647+  ee  EFI GPT

Disk /dev/sdap: 214.7 GB, 214748364800 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 26108 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

    Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System

Disk /dev/sdaq: 107.3 GB, 107374182400 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 13054 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

    Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System

Disk /dev/sdar: 3298.5 GB, 3298534883328 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 401024 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

    Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdar1               1      267350  2147483647+  ee  EFI GPT

Disk /dev/sdas: 214.7 GB, 214748364800 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 26108 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

    Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System

Disk /dev/sdat: 107.3 GB, 107374182400 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 13054 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

    Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System

Disk /dev/sdau: 3298.5 GB, 3298534883328 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 401024 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

    Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdau1               1      267350  2147483647+  ee  EFI GPT

Disk /dev/sdav: 214.7 GB, 214748364800 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 26108 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

    Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System

Disk /dev/dm-2: 214.7 GB, 214748364800 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 26108 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

     Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System

Disk /dev/dm-3: 3298.5 GB, 3298534883328 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 401024 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

     Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/dm-3p1               1      267350  2147483647+  ee  EFI GPT

Disk /dev/dm-4: 107.3 GB, 107374182400 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 13054 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

     Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
```

fc_hosts:

```
 cat /sys/class/fc_host/host[1-4]/port_name 
    0x500143802424eb38 
    0x500143802424eb3a 
    0x500143802424ec18 
    0x500143802424ec1a
```

Multipath:

```
 # multipath -ll
    mpath2 (360a98000572d505a6834737741386576) dm-4 NETAPP,LUN
    size=100G features='3 queue_if_no_path pg_init_retries 50' hwhandler='0' wp=rw
    |-+- policy='round-robin 0' prio=4 status=active
    | |- 4:0:2:0 sdaq       66:160 active ready running
    | |- 4:0:1:0 sdan       66:112 active ready running
    | |- 3:0:3:0 sdah       66:16  active ready running
    | |- 3:0:1:0 sdab       65:176 active ready running
    | |- 1:0:3:0 sdv        65:80  active ready running
    | |- 1:0:1:0 sdp        8:240  active ready running
    | |- 2:0:2:0 sdg        8:96   active ready running
    | `- 2:0:1:0 sdd        8:48   active ready running
    `-+- policy='round-robin 0' prio=1 status=enabled
      |- 4:0:3:0 sdat       66:208 active ready running
      |- 4:0:0:0 sdak       66:64  active ready running
      |- 3:0:2:0 sdae       65:224 active ready running
      |- 3:0:0:0 sdy        65:128 active ready running
      |- 1:0:2:0 sds        65:32  active ready running
      |- 1:0:0:0 sdm        8:192  active ready running
      |- 2:0:3:0 sdj        8:144  active ready running
      `- 2:0:0:0 sda        8:0    active ready running
    mpath1 (360a98000572d505a6834737741434372) dm-3 NETAPP,LUN
    size=3.0T features='3 queue_if_no_path pg_init_retries 50' hwhandler='0' wp=rw
    |-+- policy='round-robin 0' prio=4 status=active
    | |- 4:0:2:1 sdar       66:176 active ready running
    | |- 4:0:1:1 sdao       66:128 active ready running
    | |- 3:0:3:1 sdai       66:32  active ready running
    | |- 3:0:1:1 sdac       65:192 active ready running
    | |- 1:0:3:1 sdw        65:96  active ready running
    | |- 1:0:1:1 sdq        65:0   active ready running
    | |- 2:0:2:1 sdh        8:112  active ready running
    | `- 2:0:1:1 sde        8:64   active ready running
    `-+- policy='round-robin 0' prio=1 status=enabled
      |- 4:0:3:1 sdau       66:224 active ready running
      |- 4:0:0:1 sdal       66:80  active ready running
      |- 3:0:2:1 sdaf       65:240 active ready running
      |- 3:0:0:1 sdz        65:144 active ready running
      |- 1:0:2:1 sdt        65:48  active ready running
      |- 1:0:0:1 sdn        8:208  active ready running
      |- 2:0:3:1 sdk        8:160  active ready running
      `- 2:0:0:1 sdb        8:16   active ready running
    mpath0 (360a98000572d505a6834737741457870) dm-2 NETAPP,LUN
    size=200G features='3 queue_if_no_path pg_init_retries 50' hwhandler='0' wp=rw
    |-+- policy='round-robin 0' prio=4 status=active
    | |- 4:0:2:2 sdas       66:192 active ready running
    | |- 4:0:1:2 sdap       66:144 active ready running
    | |- 3:0:3:2 sdaj       66:48  active ready running
    | |- 3:0:1:2 sdad       65:208 active ready running
    | |- 1:0:3:2 sdx        65:112 active ready running
    | |- 1:0:1:2 sdr        65:16  active ready running
    | |- 2:0:2:2 sdi        8:128  active ready running
    | `- 2:0:1:2 sdf        8:80   active ready running
    `-+- policy='round-robin 0' prio=1 status=enabled
      |- 4:0:3:2 sdav       66:240 active ready running
      |- 4:0:0:2 sdam       66:96  active ready running
      |- 3:0:2:2 sdag       66:0   active ready running
      |- 3:0:0:2 sdaa       65:160 active ready running
      |- 1:0:2:2 sdu        65:64  active ready running
      |- 1:0:0:2 sdo        8:224  active ready running
      |- 2:0:3:2 sdl        8:176  active ready running
      `- 2:0:0:2 sdc        8:32   active ready running
```

dmsetup:

```
# dmsetup ls 
mpath2  (253, 4) 
mpath1  (253, 3) 
mpath0  (253, 2) 
VolGroup00-LogVol01     (253, 1) 
VolGroup00-LogVol00     (253, 0)
```

I've never had to do anything like this before so please don't beat me up. I'm just looking for what questions to ask the storage admin, and what commands to find the right drive to format and mount.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use `/dev/sd*`, as they map to single paths only.

Use `/dev/mpath*` devices (or as shown by the output of `multipath -l`).

The output `multipath -ll` shows  that the disk you want to use is `/dev/mapper/mpath1`

Make your filesystem on it, format it, partition it or what ever you like. Just **don't** use the `/dev/sd*` devices.

looking at your output,

```
mpath1 (360a98000572d505a6834737741434372) dm-3 NETAPP,LUN
size=3.0T features='3 queue_if_no_path pg_init_retries 50' hwhandler='0' wp=rw
|-+- policy='round-robin 0' prio=4 status=active
| |- 4:0:2:1 sdar       66:176 active ready running
| |- 4:0:1:1 sdao       66:128 active ready running
| |- 3:0:3:1 sdai       66:32  active ready running
| |- 3:0:1:1 sdac       65:192 active ready running
| |- 1:0:3:1 sdw        65:96  active ready running
| |- 1:0:1:1 sdq        65:0   active ready running
| |- 2:0:2:1 sdh        8:112  active ready running
| `- 2:0:1:1 sde        8:64   active ready running
`-+- policy='round-robin 0' prio=1 status=enabled
  |- 4:0:3:1 sdau       66:224 active ready running
  |- 4:0:0:1 sdal       66:80  active ready running
  |- 3:0:2:1 sdaf       65:240 active ready running
  |- 3:0:0:1 sdz        65:144 active ready running
  |- 1:0:2:1 sdt        65:48  active ready running
  |- 1:0:0:1 sdn        8:208  active ready running
  |- 2:0:3:1 sdk        8:160  active ready running
  `- 2:0:0:1 sdb        8:16   active ready running
```

the devices which make up `mpath1` represent single paths to the same disks ([multipathd](http://linux.die.net/man/8/multipathd) figures this out by looking at WWID etc). WHich means that all `sd*` disks in the output point to the same device, but are using different paths for reaching it. This is for redundancy and sometimes performence reasons.

Comment: What are all of the disks shown running under mpath1? Just a bunch of drives that as total equal 3TB for the SAN? I'm confused because if I view them with fdisk -l (ex. `fdisk -l /dev/sdar` that disk alone is 3TB but there are others that are less like sdap is 214GB)

Comment: They are single paths to your storage. using SAN you typically connect several HBA ports to several san switch ports in the SAN, each are represented by a `sd*` device name. It's for redundancy- That's why they say active running. If you pull one HBA port, then you'll note that in multipath -ll it appears as offline

Comment: Okay, thanks Petter H. Sorry for being so ignorant about this :(

Comment: no worries! I did the same mistake once, a small hiccup on the SAN fabric caused a lot of headache not only for me ;)