# Number of device listed with multipath -ll

Tags: linux, multipath

Hope i am not wasting anyone´s time, so apologies to all should that be the case with this question.

it is the first time i am playing with multipath, manged to setup multipath on a RHL5, the setup comprises of the following:

RHL5 Server has 2 x HBA - HBA1 Port1 connects to Fiber Switch 1 & HBA2 port1 connects to fiber switch 2

NETAPP FAS2040 Storage with one HBA with 2 ports, port 1 connects to Fiber Switch 1 & port 2 connects to Fiber Switch 2.

multipath -ll command show the following:

```
[root@nonameserver /]# multipath -ll
mpath0 (360a98000323766586b24422f6735626c) dm-2 NETAPP,LUN
[size=149G][features=1 queue_if_no_path][hwhandler=0]
\_ round-robin 0 [prio=2][active]
 \_ 4:0:0:0 sda 8:0   [active][ready]
 \_ 2:0:0:0 sdb 8:16  [active][ready]
```

My question is why is there two devices /dev/sda & /dev/sdb? on the storage there is only one LUN setup for the host.

Thank you all.

Comment: Hi, browsing the site i found a similar question in here http://serverfault.com/questions/532644/mounting-a-disk-from-san-rhel-5-9 but i would like to have more opinions. thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `/dev/sda` device is the target LUN as seen through one HBA, the `/dev/sdb` device is the same LUN seen through the other HBA. That's how it works - different controllers means different devices. As the other answer you commented about notes, do not use `sda` or `sdb` - use the multipath device (`/dev/mpath0`).

Comment: Hi John, does it mean then that by using the /dev/mpath0 device it would fail over to either /dev/sda or dev/sdb depending on its availability?

Comment: In simple terms and at a high level, yes, that is what multipathing does.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understand your question. This is how I do it:

`$ iscsiadm --mode discovery --type sendtargets --portal <IP:PORT>`

`$ iscsiadm -m node -l (login to all)`

`multipath -ll -v2` (This will show all devices currently connected)

`ls -la /dev/s*` (e.g. Look for the iscsi device with latest date and time)

`scsi_id -g -u -s /block/sxxxx` (e.g. Replace sxxx with the block name)

`vim /etc/multipath.conf`

```
multipath {

             wwid      <put the output of scsi_cmd here>
             alias     <your-alias>
             path_selector "round-robin 0"
             path_grouping_policy multibus
             rr_weight  uniform
             no_path_retry 5
             rr_min_io   100
}
```

`service multipath restart`

`multipath -ll -v2` (alias listed now)

`udevcontrol reload_rules`

(Now edit your fstab and add `/dev/mapper/<alias>p1   /mntpoint   ext3  _netdev 0 0`

`mkdir /mntpoint`

`parted /dev/mapper/<alias>`

`parted> mklabel gpt`

`parted> print`

`parted> name 1 alias`

`parted> print`

`parted> quit`

`ls /dev/mapper`

`mkfs.ext3 -m 0 -F /dev/mapper/<alias>p1`

`tune2fs -c 0 -i 0 /dev/mapper/<alias>p1`

`e2label /dev/mapper/<alias>p1 mntdir`

`mount -a`

*Optional: Add to NFS Server*

`vim /etc/exports`

(add mnt dir to exports if you want to share it on NFS)

Comment: why make partition on dm multipaths? a lun is storage logical partition and you did other partion on the server side, i think do that is waste your time

Comment: @c4f4t0r: this is how it is recommended in the multipath manual

Comment: @If you have a redhat network account and you ask to the author of the manual, nobody can't tell you why partitioning a lun is required